# Postman does not want to open: [ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(377)]

Tags: postman

When trying to run Postman with the command `/usr/bin/postman/Postman` I get the following error:

```bash
The disableGPU setting is set to undefined
Not disabling GPU
Main~createDefaultWorkingDir - Default working dir creation already attempted
1690885633466 main info "Booting Postman 10.16.0, linux-5.15.0-76-generic on x64"
1690885633467 main info "EventBus~initialize - Success"
1690885633469 main info "Proxy configuration has not been setup"
1690885633470 main info "CloudProxyManager~init - Success"
[5787:0801/072713.506088:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(377)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

The OS I'm using is Linux Mint 21.2.

Comment: Try setting the environment variable POSTMAN_DISABLE_GPU=true. https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/10252

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to clear my settings (using Pop_OS). I had Postman installed via flatpak, so your exact directories may be different.

Your config data here:
https://support.postman.com/hc/en-us/articles/4410785125271-How-to-remove-local-data#h_01GGSSGVHB2HR40HQ0QC7SBHHA

In Linux Mint, it's likely the same mine in Pop_OS `~/.config/Postman`.

Try opening Postman again. If it still fails, check your running processes (after attempting to run Postman) and find any processes that contain a `--user-data-dir`

```
$ ps aux | grep -i postman

59941 /app/extra/Postman/postman --type=utility [...snip] --user-data-dir=/home/me/.var/app/com.getpostman.Postman/config/Postman
```

In the example above, `/home/me/.var/com.getpostman.Postman` is being used. Delete that directory and rerun postman. After deleting, it finally opened for me.